# RegExp - need a help. Remove white space (not every)

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove whitespace from example file:

[RegEXP Online](https://regex101.com/r/lavVcJ/1)

But i want to leave spaces like:

```
       <Name>Name, Surname</Name>
       <street>Street Test Test Test</street>
```

Comment: Whitespace outside of XML tags does not necessarily even have a semantic meaning.  Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Please include all pertinent code in the question.

Comment: How about `\s\s+` or `\n\s+`? But as mentioned before, this is only for cosmetic purpose, nothing really needed.

Comment: Ok. In my specyfic situation i use only  /\s\s+/g . Thanks for sugestions !!!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to replace

```
^\s+
```

with nothing.

This matches all lines starting (`^`) with a white space character and all white spaces (`\s+`) thereafter (including new lines and tabs). All text after the first *non white space* is left as is.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lavVcJ/3).

Answer (score 0):

To answer strictly, replacing `(\s)\s*` with `\1` will keep the first white space of a group only. It does the job

In your case, it would be nicer to remove empty lines to keep the indentation, hence replace `\n\s*\n` with `\n`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

`^\s+|\r?\n|^"\s+|\s+"$`

https://regex101.com/r/lavVcJ/8

It will also remove the `"` at the beginning and the end. So if you need them, just remember to add them after the replacement is done.